# Nested ng-include makes AngularJS load infinitely

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a Rails 4 App with such an **assets filetree**:

```
- Assets
- - Javascripts
- - - ng-controllers
- - - - parrotsController.coffee
- - - ng-views
- - - - partials
- - - - - _parrots_index.html.slim
- - - - - _parrots_index_paginator.html.slim
- - - - home.html.slim
- - - app.coffee
- - - routes_config.coffee
```

**routes_config.coffee**:

```
...
    $routeProvider
      .when '/',
        templateUrl: 'ng-views/home.html',
        controller: 'ParrotsController as vm' # Modern 'as' syntax
                                              # 'vm' goes for ViewModel
      .otherwise
        redirectTo: '/'
...
```

**home.html.slim**:

```
...
  div ng-include="'ng-views/partials/_parrots_index.html'"
...
```

**_parrots_index.html.slim**:

```
...
  tr ng-include="'ng-views/partials/_parrots_index_paginator.html.slim'"
...
```

**_parrots_index_paginator.html.slim**:

```
td
  | Some content, no models here
```

So, if I do not ng-include **_parrots_index_paginator.html.slim** within **_parrots_index.html.slim** but just insert its code, **it works fine** (even if it's inserted twice).

However, leaving everything as in the code listed above leads to infinite assets loading. Why?

My **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'angularjs-rails', git: 'https://github.com/ScoutRFP/angularjs-rails' # <- Better fork
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
gem 'angular_rails_csrf'
```

**application.coffee**:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require bootstrap-sprockets
#= require angular
#= require angular-resource
#= require angular-route
#= require angular-animate
#= require angular-rails-templates
#= require angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min
#= require angular-loading-bar

#= require_tree .
```

Thanks for any help and let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 0):

In your example of `_parrots_index.html.slim`, you have:

```
...
tr ng-include="'ng-views/partials/_parrots_index_paginator.html.slim'"
...
```

Shouldn't that be including the HTML file (not `.slim`)?